# Pages appearing in black on Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, colors, firefox-developer-edition

I just installed the latest Firefox Developer's Edition (40.0a2) on one of my VMs, and most web pages are showing up on it (images included) as one big black page of nothing. (It works fine on my host system.) How do I fix this so that I can use the new browser for web development on my VM?

Firefox (37.0.1) itself also works fine on the VM.

Comment: Is HW accel on or off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and then click Tools -> Options (OR click the hamburger -> Options)

In the General tab, there is a panel called Startup. In here, you need to uncheck "Enable multi-process Firefox Developer Edition" (e10s)

Comment: That did it. It's quite weird, though, because the dev edition works just fine on my physical PC with multi-process enabled.