# Firefox Developer Edition shows black screen

Tags: firefox

I have Firefox Dev edition.

I also have a Speed Dial application.

When I load FireFox, the speed dial shows as desired. When I click on any web page, all I see is a black screen.

I disabled hardware rendering. The same issue persists.

Unlike this question [Pages appearing in black on Firefox Developer Edition](https://superuser.com/questions/931233/pages-appearing-in-black-on-firefox-developer-edition/931566#931566) , I am not using a VM and the issue occurs on my home PC and work PC. They do not share any apps or sync.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and then click Tools -> Options (OR click the hamburger -> Options)

In the General tab, there is a panel called Startup. In here, you need to uncheck "Enable multi-process Firefox Developer Edition" (e10s)